# rearrange xml nodes by xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am beginner to use the XSLT. I had an XMl with different attributes and my aim is to create a new XML with respective order pattern of attributes. For this I am using the below XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <channel>
                    <title>Test Data</title>
                    <link>http://www.google.com</link>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="products/product" />

                </channel>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="products/product">
            <item>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="products/product/@*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="products/product/Parent_identifier | products/product/Unique_ID | products/product/EAN> 
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sample XML is as Follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<products>
  <product>
    <EAN>9999999999975</EAN>
    <Parent_identifier>BP_100001766</Parent_identifier>
    <Unique_ID>999999975</Unique_ID>
  </product>
  <product>
    <EAN>99000009999975</EAN>
    <Parent_identifier>BP_10066</Parent_identifier>
    <Unique_ID>999000975</Unique_ID>
  </product>
  <product>
    <EAN>99111119999975</EAN>
    <Parent_identifier>BP_10222066</Parent_identifier>
    <Unique_ID>99911110975</Unique_ID>
  </product>
</products>
```

My expected out put XML is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<products>
  <product>
    <Parent_identifier>BP_100001766</Parent_identifier>
    <Unique_ID>999999975</Unique_ID>
    <EAN>9999999999975</EAN>
  </product>
  <product>
    <Parent_identifier>BP_10066</Parent_identifier>
    <Unique_ID>999000975</Unique_ID>
    <EAN>99000009999975</EAN>
  </product>
  <product>
    <Parent_identifier>BP_10222066</Parent_identifier>
    <Unique_ID>99911110975</Unique_ID>
    <EAN>99111119999975</EAN>
  </product>
</products>
```

Can anyone help me to find out my mistake and to get expected output

Comment: I suggest you spend an hour going through an XSLT tutorial. That should about all that's necessary for this trivial task.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion -  michael

Comment: There are no attributes in this XML. Your sample input/output shows that you are trying to change the order of *elements*. Most of your uses of `@*` in your stylesheet should therefore be changed to `*`.

Answer (score 3):

There are no attributes in this XML. Your sample input/output shows that you are trying to change the order of **elements**. Most of your uses of `@*` in your stylesheet should therefore be changed to `*`.

To output elements in a different order from the input, select them explicitly in the apply-templates:

**XSLT 2.0/3.0**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Parent_identifier, Unique_ID, EAN"/>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Parent_identifier"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Unique_ID"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="EAN"/>
```

Comment: After replacing @* with * my xml is transformed but the order of elements is not as excepted. can you please help.

Comment: I had tired with suggestion of XSLT 1.0

Comment: If you've corrected one problem and are now moving on to another problem, the best thing to do is to raise a new question. The StackOverflow format doesn't allow for supplementary questions like this. Start from the beginning: give your input, expected output, and current XSLT code.